# Why is this true: $\ker(d_{C,i-1})=H_i(C_*)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology

I try to understand the proof of the long exact sequence of homology. The proof uses the snake lemma, which is logic but I don't get one point: We end with the following diagram:
[image]
Why do we have that $\ker(d_{C,i-1})=H_i(C_*)=\ker(d_{C,i})/ im(d_{C,i})$?

Comment: I pretty sure $H_i(C_*)\ne\ker(d_{C,i-1})$... also an index in the definition of $H_i$ is wrong.

Comment: I am sorry but this is how the proof of the long exact sequence of homology looks like, not? (See for example here:https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0111)

Comment: Yes, sure. Use the snake lemma in the diagram... the map $d_{C,i}=d_{C,i}^{induced}$ in the diagram is the induced map to the quotient from the original $d_{C,i}$, and $\ker(d_{C,i}^{induced})=\ker(d_{C,i}) / im(d_{C,i+1})\subset C_i/ im(d_{C,i+1})$.

Comment: yeah but why the last equality holds? See also last line of my question…

Comment: The last line should be $\ker(d_{C,i})=H_i(C_*)=\ker(d_{C,i})/ im(d_{C,i+1})$, but in the sense of my last comment $\ker(d_{C,i}^{induced})=H_i(C_*)=\ker(d_{C,i})/ im(d_{C,i+1})$. I remark the map $d_{C,i}^{induced}$ isn't the map $d_{C,i}$ of the original complex...